# Creating a gif from pngs: looping through images seems too fast and only works in debug mode

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, png, gif, python-imageio

I'm trying to create a gif image from several (in this case only 5) png files. I can create the gif if I debug the code at the point the looping through the images occurs. Otherwise the execution appears to be too fast. Here is my code:

```
img, *imgs = [Image.open(f) for f in sorted(glob.glob(png_in))]
```

So I flattened the list comprehension and added and played around with the `time.sleep(x)`:

```
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True
imgs = []
for f in sorted(glob.glob(png_in)):
    i = Image.open(f)
    time.sleep(1)
    imgs.append(i)
```

Then instead of using the PIL module, I switched to the `imageio` module:

```
images = []
png_list = sorted(glob.glob(png_in))
for filename in png_list:
    print(f"fn: {filename}")
    images.append(imageio.imread(filename))
    time.sleep(1)
imageio.mimsave(gif_file, images)
```

Any ideas where I may be going wrong? The error message I get, for example, is:

```
unknown element "blank"
    i = Image.open(f)
```

Comment: *"Too fast"* for **what** exactly please? What are you trying to do and what is the actual problem? Try checking the names in your list of files - you may be picking up dot-files or invalid files.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: by too fast, I mean that in pycharm simply running the script doesn't work and error messages get thrown in the for loop (as if opening  the image takes too long). If I debug, add a bullit point where the for loop is, and then F8, all works accordingly.

Comment: Try inspecting `sorted(glob.glob(png_in))`

Comment: @MarkSetchell: it's just a list of strings (path and file name of each *.png).

Comment: @MarkSetchell: thanks Mark (see my answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Mark Setchell....the problem I found was that the png's were not all there at the point the for loop was executed. I'm using openscad to create png files, and it's here I need to implement a `time.sleep`. In debug mode, because it's slower, openscad had time to create the png's and so you don't see this problem.

Comment: Well sleuthed! Thank you for sharing back with the SO community.